# css - stretched and evenly spaced horizontal menu

Tags: html, css, alignment, stretch

I hope, you can help me, I have a horizontal menu, my problem is the following:

[image]

The first is normal stretch with table, the second is what I want: **stretch + even gaps between texts**.

I achieved this with additional non breaking spaces, but it works only by fixed menu widths, so if I change the menu width I have to change the count of the nbsp characters. Is there any way to do this with css, and without those non breaking spaces?

**The count of the menupoints and the menu width can change, so I need an automatical solution without javascript. No settings by individual columns, unless you can give me an algorithm which I can run on server side.**

I don't think this is possible with css only, but I'm not a css guru, that's why I asked....

```
<style>
    * {
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px;
        font-size: 16px;
    }

    table {
        width: 400px;
    }

    td {
        border: 1px solid blue;
        text-align: center;
    }
</style>

<table>
    <tr>
        <td><a href="#">aa</a></td>
        <td><a href="#">aaaaaaaaaaaaa</a></td>
        <td><a href="#">aaaaaaaaa</a></td>
    </tr>
</table>


<table>
    <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="#">aa</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="#">aaaaaaaaaaaaa</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="#">aaaaaaaaa</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure of all the parameters here ("stretch" is not very clear), but wouldn't some left and right padding on the links do it? Because this is a menu, I won't use a table but a `<ul>` instead. There are plenty of variations on this if it's not what you want:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">

<style media="all">
ul, li {margin: 0; padding: 0;}
ul {list-style: none; display: table; border-spacing: 5px; }
li {display: table-cell; background: #f7f7f7; border: 1px solid blue; }
li a {padding: 0 30px;}
</style>

</head>
<body>

<ul>
    <li><a href="#">aa</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">aaaaaaaaaaaaa</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">aaaaaaaaa</a></li>
</ul>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: OK, I'm wondering if, by "stretch", you mean that the menu always stretches to a width of 100%? If so, then back to the drawing board. :-)

Comment: Stretch not working if I resize the window, but if I change the width manually, then it works. I don't know why padding helped, but it's perfect! :-) Thanks! :-)

Comment: There is a slight difference if you have this 3 menupoint in a huge horizontal space, but I usually have at least 5-6 menupoints, so it is good enough for me. Thanks again! :-)

Answer (score 2):

**Edit: The below answer does not work well with Internet Explorer versions as recent as IE 11. Its algorithm for cell sizing appears to work differently than other browsers.**

While this will require some cross-browser testing, here's what I've been using:

http://jsfiddle.net/aaronadams/j3cEQ/

HTML:

```
<p>Default spacing:</p>
<ul>
    <li>aa</li>
    <li>aaaa aaaa aaaa</li>
    <li>aaa aaa aaa</li>
    <li>aa aa</li>
</ul>
<p>Even spacing:</p>
<ul class="even">
    <li>aa</li>
    <li>aaaa aaaa aaaa</li>
    <li>aaa aaa aaa</li>
    <li>aa aa</li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
ul {
    display: table;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 30em;
    text-align: center;
}
li {
    display: table-cell;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0 0.125em;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
.even li {
    width: 1%;
}
```

So far, this is providing me with a menu that works really well across all screen sizes; on mobile it shrinks to screen width, on desktop it grows up to a certain size, and the links are always evenly spaced.

Credit here for the inspiration: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16509901/802414

Comment: Works in firefox and chrome, but not in MSIE.

Comment: @inf3rno Which versions? IE8 and below don't support display: table-cell, but even then the menu still seems to render adequately.

Comment: `MSIE 11.0.9600`  
why can't I send a short comment?! :S

Comment: @inf3rno Good eye, I can confirm it doesn't work well. Its algorithm seems to fall back to equal cell sizing,

Answer (score 0):

You can set the width for the individual columns.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YhTcS/)

**HTML**

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td class="first"><a href="#">aa</a></td>
        <td class="second"><a href="#">aaaaaaaaaaaaa</a></td>
        <td class="third"><a href="#">aaaa aaaaaaaaaaaaa</a></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**CSS**

```
table {
    width: 400px;
}

td {
    border: 1px solid #d3d3d3;
    text-align: center;
}

.first {
    width: 30%;
}

.second {
    width: 45%;
}

.third {
    width: 30%;
}
```

Comment: Yes I know, but this is not automatical... I'll edit my question, just a minute.

Answer (score 0):

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/YhTcS/6/)

You can set the "padding left and right for individual column

**HTML**

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td class="first"><a href="#">aa</a></td>
        <td class="second"><a href="#">aaaaaaaaaaaaa</a></td>
        <td class="third"><a href="#">aaaa aaaaaaaaaaaaa</a></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**CSS**

```
table { width: 400px; }
td { border: 1px solid #d3d3d3; text-align: center;}
.first { padding: 0 3em; }
.second { padding: 0 2em; }
.third { padding: 0 4em; }
```

Comment: Edited twice, maybe it's obvious now. :-)

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved with CSS by making the parent element text-align: justify, and the child elements display:inline-block;  However, justified text only works properly when there's at least 2 lines.  The pseudo :after element is used to force an extra (very tiny) line:

```
#container {
  height: 125px;
  text-align: justify;
  border: 10px solid black;
  font-size: 0.1px; /* IE 9/10 don't like font-size: 0; */
  min-width: 600px;
}
#container div {
  width: 150px;
  height: 125px;
  display: inline-block;
  background: red;
}
#container:after {
  content: '';
  width: 100%; /* Ensures there are at least 2 lines of text, so justification works */
  display: inline-block;
}
```

Credit to https://css-tricks.com/equidistant-objects-with-css/ for this technique.